# Как получить правильный массив

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, состоящий из букв латинского алфавита. С помощью метода indexOf нужно получить только индексы буквы ‘a’. То есть исходя из примера консоль должна выдать такой результат: [0, 1, 2, 4]. Реализовать перебор нужно именно с for().

```
function n(array) {


let indices = [];
  let element = 'a';
  let idx = array.indexOf(element);
  for (let i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
  indices.push(idx[i]);
 }
  return indices
}
  
  console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']))
```

Comment: Вот массив ['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd'], который нужно преобразовать в индексы элементов ‘а’, то есть должно получиться [0, 1, 2, 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Условия, конечно, искусственные, ну, на то оно и учебное задание) Можно так:

```js
function n(array) {
  const indices = [];
  const element = 'a';

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ) {
    const index = array.indexOf(element, i);
    if (index > -1) {
      indices.push(index);
      i = index + 1;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return indices;
}

console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']));
```

P.S.: когда перебираете массив, используйте `i < array.length`, а не `i <= array.length`, иначе выйдете за границы массива.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const el = 'a';
const n = (a) => a.reduce((ac, c, i) => {
  if (c === el) ac.push(i);
  return ac;
}, []);

console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']));
console.log(n(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']));
```

Либо так:

```js
const el='a';
const n=(a)=>a.map((e,i)=>e===el?i:null).filter(Number.isInteger);

console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']));
console.log(n(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']));
```

Либо по условия задачи с циклом:

```js
const el = 'a';
const n = (a) => {
  const acc = [];
  for (const [i, e] of a.entries())
    if (e === el) acc.push(i);
  return acc;
};

console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']));
console.log(n(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']));
```

Либо по условию задачи с циклом `while` и `indexOf`:

```js
const el = 'a';
const n = (a) => {
  const acc = [];
  let i = -1;
  while ((i = a.indexOf(el, i + 1)) != -1) 
    acc.push(i);
  return acc;
};

console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']));
console.log(n(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']));
```

Либо по условию задачи с циклом `for` и `indexOf`:

```js
const el = 'a';
const n = (a) => {
  const acc = [];
  let i = -1;
  for (i=a.indexOf(el); i != -1; i = a.indexOf(el, i + 1))
        acc.push(i);
  return acc;
};

console.log(n(['a', 'a', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'd']));
console.log(n(['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']));
```